# How to show that $b_n(n) \neq 0$ for $b_n(x) = -\frac{16 x}{n} b_{n-1}(x) - \frac{48 x}{n} b_{n-2}(x)$?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

Lets define the recursive polynomial:

$b_0(x) = 1$

$b_1(x) = -16 x$

$b_n(x) = -\frac{16 x}{n} \left( b_{n-1}(x) + 3 b_{n-2}(x) \right) = -\frac{16 x}{n} b_{n-1}(x) - \frac{48 x}{n} b_{n-2}(x)$ ; with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Question 1: How can I show that $b_n(n) \neq 0$ ?**

I can show that for the following recurrence relation $a_n \neq 0$.

$a_0 = 1$

$a_1 = -16$

$a_n = -16 \left( a_{n-1} + 3 a_{n-2} \right) = -16 a_{n-1} - 48 a_{n-2}$

The characteristic polynomial will be:

$\lambda^2 + 16\lambda + 48 = 0$

with the solutions $\lambda_1 = -12$ and $\lambda_2 = -4$.

Therefore I am able to express $a_n$ as:

$a_n = A_1 \lambda_1^n + A_2 \lambda_2^n = \frac{3}{2}(-12)^n - \frac{1}{2}(-4)^n = (-1)^n \frac{12^n - 4^n}{2} \neq 0$

My motivation was numerical evidence and that:

$b_n(n) = -16 \left( b_{n-1}(n) + 3 b_{n-2}(n) \right)$ which is like $a_n$ but

$b_{n-1}(n) = -16 \frac{n-1}{n} \left( b_{n-2}(n) + 3 b_{n-3}(n) \right)$ for example is only similar to $a_{n-1}$ in the long run when $n \to \infty$.

**Question 2: Is it possible in any way to proof $b_n(n) \neq 0$ by using $a_n$ ?**

Comment: Sorry I don't have a proof yet. But from the first glimpse, your recursive definition of $a_n$ is wrong.You mixed the notation of $n$ and $x$.

Comment: assuming you define $a_n = b_n(n)$, but $b_{n-1}(n)$ is not in the definition of $a_n$ series.

Comment: I checked my definition of $a_n$. The definition, as I want to be, is correct written down.

Comment: @MoonKnight I have here broken down my big question to this specific example. In a general definition I see numerically an asymptotic connection between $b_n(n)$ and $a_n$ for many more similar examples.

Answer (score 1):

If we fix $n$ and define $a_k=b_k(n)$, then indeed we obtain a recursion
$$a_0=1,\quad a_1=-16n,\quad a_k=-16a_{k-1}-48a_{k-2}. $$
From here we infer that
$$\tag1 a_k=A(-12)^k+B(-4)^k$$
for suitable $A,B$.
The desired result is that this makes $a_n\ne0$.
Clearly, $a_0\ne 0$. Also, when $n=1$, we have $a_1=-16\ne 0$, so that we need only consider the cases with $n\ge 2$.

From $(1)$ and the given values for $a_0,a_1$,  we  infer $$\tag2A+B=1,\quad -12A-4B=-16n,$$
Or more explicitely
$$ \tag3A=2n-\frac12,\quad B=\frac32-2n.$$
Note that $a_n=0$ implies
$$\frac BA=-3^n\le -9, $$whereas $(3)$ leads to 
$$\frac BA=\frac{\frac32-2n}{2n-\frac12}=-1+\frac1{2n-\frac12}>-1. $$

Comment: I am familiar with your way of solving. I have done it the same way, too. But for me it is unclear if I can say directly that $b_n(x) \neq 0$ at the position where $x = n$ because the defined $a_k = b_k(n) \neq 0$. For example $b_3(3) = -16 \left( b_2(3) + 3 b_1(3) \right) \neq a_3 = -16 \left( a_2 + 3 a_3 \right)$

Comment: Edit: For example $b_3(3) = −16 \left( b_2(3)+3 b_1(3) \right) \neq a_3 = −16 \left( a_2 + 3 a_1 \right)$